# Click on next element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple same containers and each one contains same anchors like:

```
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button1">Button 1a</a>
  <a href="#" class="button2">Button 2a</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button1">Button 1b</a>
  <a href="#" class="button2">Button 2b</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button1">Button 1c</a>
  <a href="#" class="button2">Button 2c</a>
</div>
```

What I try to achieve is when I click on .button1 should start trigger and auto click on closest .button2

My js code now looks like:

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.button1')

btn.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
         console.log(this.innerText)
       this.closest('.button2').click()
    });
});
```

And here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4nhvtao1/4/

Comment: Try to use [Element.nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling)

Comment: closest walks up the tree. It does not look at siblings....

Comment: `closest` is for looking for an ancestor. [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) maybe a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closest` moves up the dom hierarchy to try to find the selector you specify. It would be better to use the sibling (~) selector (or you can just use node.nextElementSibling in this case)

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.button1')

btn.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
//         console.log(this.innerText)
      //var other = this.nextElementSibling;
      var other = this.parentNode.querySelector(".button1 ~ .button2")
      console.log(other);
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button1">Button 1a</a>
  <a href="#" class="button2">Button 2a</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button1">Button 1b</a>
  <a href="#" class="button2">Button 2b</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button1">Button 1c</a>
  <a href="#" class="button2">Button 2c</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't really understand the purpose of this, here is an approach...

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.innerText)
    e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.click()
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" id="button1a" class="btn">Button 1a</a>
  <a href="#" id="button2a" class="btn">Button 2a</a>
<div>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="button1b" class="btn">Button 1b</a>
  <a href="#" id="button2b" class="btn">Button 2b</a>
<div>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="button1c" class="btn">Button 1c</a>
  <a href="#" id="button2c" class="btn">Button 2c</a>
<div>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="button1d" class="btn">Button 1d</a>
  <a href="#" id="button2d" class="btn">Button 2d</a>
<div>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="button1e" class="btn">Button 1e</a>
  <a href="#" id="button2e" class="btn">Button 2e</a>
<div>
```